# static linking ICU4C makes uregex functions fail

Tags: c, icu

I am going to use ICU4C unicode library with version 4.2.1 (the version which is packaged in Ubuntu 10.04). I made a simple test code; just opening a regular expression object.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <unicode/utypes.h>
#include <unicode/uregex.h>

int main() {
    UChar zPattern[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 0};
    UErrorCode status = 0;
    URegularExpression *pExpr = uregex_open(zPattern, -1, 0, 0, &status);
    return status;
};
```

I compiled with dynamically-linked icu library and ran, like below:

```
gcc -o test.out test.c -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lpthread -lm
./test.out
```

and the result status code was '0'. worked like a charm.

Now I decided to link icu library statically like below, and ran

```
gcc -o test.out -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION test.c -lsicui18n -lsicuuc -lsicudata -lpthread -lstdc++ -lm
./test.out
```

and the result status code was '1'. uregex_open function failed with the status code 'U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR'.

Did I missed something to link ICU4C statically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the libsicudata you ended up hitting- it's probably the 'stub' one. If you want ICU's data to be loaded as a static library, it should be a several-meg libicusdata.

To debug ICU loading issues, call  `u_init(&status)` first, that will see if ICU can load its data. I don't know how ubuntu builds ICU, maybe the data is loaded in a different way (such as from a file).

Comment: I found that the libsicudata.a file packaged in ubuntu is quite small (about 1kb). I couldn't figure out how I can use the data file that may be reside outside this library file. So I decided to build the static icu library by myself and link with my project. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome! Maybe something to file a bug about.  The other option might be that the data is loaded from a file, such as /usr/share/icu/icudt*.dat on the Mac platform. Depending on your project's needs (you may not need conversion, collation, or locale data, for example) you might save some space by customizing data with the data customizer. See http://userguide.icu-project.org/icudata